# Add group of items to List

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to get a collection of items from  web api.

```
var sampleDataGroups = new List<SampleDataGroup>();

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    // CL: Parse 1 Product from the content
    var product = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(content);

    foreach (var data in product)
    {
        var dataGroup = new SampleDataGroup
        (
            (string)product.Id.ToString(),
            (string)product.Name,
            (string)"",
            (string)product.PhotoUrl,
            (string)product.Description
        );
        sampleDataGroups.Add(dataGroup);
    }
}
```

I am attempting to use this for each to add each product info returned to a SampleDataGroup List. so that I can view the list of all products returned in that list.

This is the products list I am trying to return from the web api

```
public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
{
    return products;
}
```

But I am getting an exception error.

How do I write/add each product returned to the SampleDataGroups List?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' does not contain a definition for 'Id'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access `data` instead of `product` in your loop's body:

```
foreach (var data in product)
{
    var dataGroup = new SampleDataGroup(
        (string)data.Id.ToString(),
        (string)data.Name,
        (string)"",
        (string)data.PhotoUrl,
        (string)data.Description);

    sampleDataGroups.Add(dataGroup);
}
```